# Is there a way to send a post through url but with open the page using www ? Looks like a combine Unity c#

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I want to send a post through url but I want when send a post the page is open inside a browse.

Example :

```
IEnumerator Get_Donate_Option()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);

        WWWForm formDate = new WWWForm();

        formDate.AddField("id_user_account", user_account_detail.Id_user_account);
        formDate.AddField("device_unique_indentifier",

             using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(web_url.url_get_donate_option, formDate))
        {
            yield return www.Send();

        }
    }
```

When run the code above, I want also open the page with a browse.
I need a data send from unity and continue the process via the browser page.
I want need the unity to go to the controller of the web and get the post data from unity and then the controller will open the web page inside unity and then process for further.

If I just run the code www above I cannot process the data further via web.

Is they anything I can do ?

Thank You

Comment: You can use `Application.OpenUrl(string url)` to open web pages.

Comment: @bolkay i use a mobile ios, i cannot use that function. And also it will not send the post data if i just openURL

Comment: @bolkay I think the problem is that the target page uses PHP and requires the values from the `POST` in order to look up stuff / authenticate the user from a Database. Therefore simply calling only the URL results in a `GET` request and wouldn't pass on the required parameters...

Comment: Hey I found [this post](http://neuro-coder.com/gamedev/sending-information-unity-browser/#) which looks like it could solve your problems. The idea would be to open a normal URL page using `Application.OpenURL`. It uses JavaScript to open a local port and waits for information. Then Unity sends it's information to this port using TCP. Then the JavaScript does the actual Post request itself. I'll test that as soon as I have a PC ;) might still not work with mobile phone since the browser probably opens on top of Unity...

Comment: @derHugo it is look like using Get is the way to do this. But still it is not safe enough. To make it secure i am using https but still not really safe. I am developing a mobile apps. So it is no use for application.openurl and for the post you refer.

Comment: @derHugo the post you recommend is it work ?, is it safe ?